# Calling a method from a segmented control to another

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol, parentviewcontroller

Here's the issue: I have a view controller with a segmented control and want to send data from segment A to segment B using a button. At the same time, I need to make segment B active and call a method there. At segment A my data is on a tableView, I need to send only **one** value from **one** cell to the other segment.

I seem to be stuck in this for a while. Tried to send the data from the child to parent to child and tried child to child but always crash the app.

Comment: When you click on a button, first get data that you want to pass.
Then create a class method in Segment B controller.
Now set your segment's selectedIndex to B's index and call newly created class method with parameters.
This will show Segment B on screen and call your method as well

Answer (score 0):

You first need to create an IBOutlet (reference) of  the segmented controller and then catch the changed value in the code by creating a corresponding method with IBAction and linking it again to the controller. Check this tutorial on how to set it all up http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/create-segmented-control-ios7